# Where can I find javax.annotation.Resource processor

Tags: java, annotations

I'm working on the Spring project with Java 8. I'm interesting in how elements with javax.annotation.Resource annotation precisely being processed. Where can I find processor for that annotation? I mean processor which should be run during compile time.